# Not able to login in liferay 6.2 with IP address with port

Tags: java, jboss7.x, liferay-6

I am new to lifI have installed liferay 6.2 with jboss-7.1.1 . 
I am able to login into liferay by  localhost:8080 but not with IP address and port 
(basically its HTTPS e.g `https://172.16.91.202:10000/`) . I tried to debug and I came to know that liferay is not rendering the port . 
Hence after login , I am being redirected to a link with no port in it . 
The result is browser refuses to connect the server. I have attached the screenshot for help.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set this properties:

```
web.server.https.port   = 10000
```

for properties setting see: 
[Liferay: How to configure Liferay Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983343/liferay-how-to-configure-liferay-portal)

Comment: Yeah, I also thought of that based on the second screenshot (the URL there does not contain the port number).

Comment: Thanks. This works .  But still I have a query, I am actually migrating from  liferay 6.0  to 6.2 . Earlier we did not put any such property, still it was working. Why such thing was left open by liferay ?