# Overriding Liferay's "autodeploy.enabled" property in Tomcat cluster environment

Tags: tomcat, liferay-6

Need to override Liferay's portal-ext.properties in Tomcat cluster environment so that two Tomcats have

```
autodeploy.enabled=true and 
autodeploy.enabled=false
```

respectively. I had followed the below link to override portal-ext.properties -

[Liferay: How to configure Liferay Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983343/liferay-how-to-configure-liferay-portal)

However the problem here is that the Liferay's home is common to both the tomcat's and both of them share the same portal-ext.properties and changing autodeploy.enabled=true overrides both Tomcat's autodeploy property. Also the webapp location is NAS mounted and both share the same webapp location.

What do I need to do to make autodeploy.enabled property different for both the Tomcats ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution after reading tomcat documentation.

1. Create two folders for example - 'portalProperties1' and 'portalProperties2' which is accessible by both the tomcats and copy portal-ext.properties in both the folders.
2. Go to the location - {liferay_home}/tomcat/conf of first Tomcat and open the file catalina.properties.
3. Search for the attribute - common.loader and add one more comman separated value - /home/flex/portalProperties1 at the end where /home/flex is the absolute path to folder portalProperties1 and will change accordingly.
4. Follow the same for other tomcat instance but replace portalProperties1 with portalProperties2.
5. Open portalProperties1/portal-ext.properties and change the property - auto.deploy.enabled = false.
   Do it for this tomcat only.
6. Restart both the Tomcats.

That's it, now only one tomcat will do the auto deployment and no exception will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution here would be to put the autodeploy.enabled=true and autodeploy.enabled=false in the portal-ext.properties inside the ROOT web application.
If you don't already have one you can create a portal-ext.properties and place it in the folder /tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/

You will need to make sure you don't have the value autodeploy.enabled=true or false in the portal-ext.properties in the liferay root folder.

Liferay checks for portal-ext.properties in both locations.

This was you can keep all your common portal-ext.properties values in one file.

Comment: The problem here is that the webapps folder is NAS mounted and both Tomcats have the same webapps folder. So there will be only one portal-ext.properties file if you put it inside ROOT folder which is shared across both the tomcats.